# NSLevelIndicator: detect click and update

Tags: objective-c, nslevelindicator

I want to use a `NSLevelIndicator` to manage ratings in my apps but I don' t understand how to detect click on it and update the ratings.

This is the code: the property `rate` is created in the .h file and it's an IBOutlet correctly linked in IB.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    NSLevelIndicatorCell *cell = [[NSLevelIndicatorCell alloc] initWithLevelIndicatorStyle:NSRatingLevelIndicatorStyle];

    [cell setMinValue:0.0];
    [cell setMaxValue:5.0];

    [cell setFloatValue:3.0];

    [cell setTarget:self];

    [cell setAction:@selector(click:)];

    [self.rate setCell:cell];


}

- (IBAction)click:(id)sender
{

    //How to detect change in rating here???

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post the solution for other people with the same "issue".

The reason why the user interaction not works for me is because i need to call `[cell setEnabled:YES]`.
Probably this property is set to `NO` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a mistake but setEnabled: does not solve any problem, while setEditable: do.